# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in codeigniter (tiara)

Tags: codeigniter, join, foreach, multiple-tables

i get error in the CI view page, as Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
this is my code :

---

---

my database:
(table of Penyewa)

```
**id_penyewa                        
nama_penyewa                                 
alamat                               
no_telp**
```

(table of Jaminan)

```
**id_penyewa                        
jenis_jaminan
ket_jaminan**
```

in Controller (penyewa.php)

```
function Penyewa()
{
    parent::Controller();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('model_tampil');
}

function tambah()
{
    $ck=$this->input->post('id_penyewa');
        if($ck!='')
        {
            $this->model_tampil->insertPenyewa();
        }
    $this->load->view('tampilpenyewa');
}

function sukses()
{
echo "Data berhasil di input!";
?>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/login/input_penyewa">Tambah Data</a>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/login/tampil_penyewa">Lihat Data</a>
<?php
}
```

in Model (model_tampil.php)

```
function getPenyewa(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('penyewa');
    $this->db->join('jaminan','jaminan.id_penyewa = penyewa.id_penyewa');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $rows = $q->num_rows(); 
    $q_result = $q->result();

    if($rows>0){
        foreach($q_result as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
function insertPenyewa()
{   
    /*$this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO penyewa VALUES($id_penyewa, $nama_penyewa, $alamat, $no_telp, $jenis_jaminan)');
    $table1_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO jaminan VALUES(id_penyewa,' . $table1_id .',jenis_jaminan)');

    $this->db->trans_complete(); */

    $this->id_penyewa=$this->input->post('id_penyewa');
    $this->nama_penyewa=$this->input->post('nama_penyewa');
    $this->alamat=$this->input->post('alamat');
    $this->no_telp=$this->input->post('no_telp');
    $this->jenis_jaminan=$this->input->post('jenis_jaminan');

    $this->db->insert('penyewa',$this); 
            redirect('penyewa/sukses');
}
```

in views (tampilPenyewa.php)

> ```
>     <center>
> <h3>Tabel data Penyewa</h3>
> <table border="1">
> <tr align="center" bgcolor="#33CC99">
> <td width="100">ID Penyewa</td>
> <td width="200">Nama Penyewa</td>
> <td width="120">Alamat</td>
> <td width="150">Nomor Telepon</td>
> <td width="150">Jenis Jaminan</td>
> <td>Tindakan Lanjut</td>
> </tr>
>
> <?php foreach ($records as $row) : ?>
> <tr height="35">
> <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row->id_penyewa; ?></td>
> <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row->nama_penyewa; ?></td>
> <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row->alamat; ?></td>
> <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row->no_telp; ?></td>
> <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row->ket_jaminan; ?></td>
> <td></td>
> </tr>
> <?php endforeach; ?>
> </table>
> <br />
>
> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/login/input_penyewa">Tambah Data</a>
> ```

and in views too (inputpenyewa.php)

> ```
> <center>
> <?php
>
> $this->load->library('validation');
> $id_penyewa=array(
>               'name'          => 'id_penyewa',
>               'id'            => 'id_penyewa',
>               'value'         => '',
>               'maxlength'     => '100',
>               'size'          => '50',
>               'validation'    => "required");
> $nama_penyewa=array(
>               'name'          => 'nama_penyewa',
>               'id'            => 'nama_penyewa',
>               'value'         => '',
>               'maxlength'     => '100',
>               'size'          => '50',
>               'validation'    => "required");
> $alamat=array(
>               'name'          => 'alamat',
>               'id'            => 'alamat',
>               'value'         => '',
>               'maxlength'     => '500',
>               'size'          => '',
>               'validation'    => "required");
> $no_telp=array(
>               'name'          => 'no_telp',
>               'id'            => 'no_telp',
>               'value'         => '',
>               'maxlength'     => '100',
>               'size'          => '50',
>               'validation'    => "required");
> $ket_jaminan=array(
>               'name'          => 'jenis_jaminan',
>               'id'            => 'jenis_jaminan',
>               'value'         => '',
>               'maxlength'     => '100',
>               'size'          => '50',
>               'validation'    => "required");
>
> $this->load->helper('form');
> echo validation_errors();
> echo form_open('penyewa/tambah');
> echo '<center><h3>Input Data Penyewa</h3></center>';
> echo "<table border='0' class='tabledetail' align='center'>";
> echo
>   "<tr>"."<td>".form_label('ID')."</td>"."<td>".form_input('id_penyewa')."</td>"."</tr>";
> echo
>   "<tr height=50>"."<td>".form_label('Nama Penyewa')."</td>"."<td>".form_input('nama_penyewa')."</td>"."</tr>";
> echo
>   "<tr height=220>"."<td>".form_label('Alamat')."</td>"."<td>".form_textarea('alamat')."</td>"."</tr>";
> echo
>   "<tr>"."<td>".form_label('No Telp')."</td>"."<td>".form_input('no_telp')."</td>"."</tr>";
> echo
>   "<tr height=220>"."<td>".form_label('Jaminan')."</td>"."<td>".form_textarea('jenis_jaminan')."</td>"."</tr>";
> echo
>   "<tr height=50>"."<td colspan=2 align='center'>".form_submit('mysubmit','Simpan')."</td>"."</tr>";
> echo "</table>";
> echo form_close();
> ?>
> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/login/tampil_penyewa">Lihat Data</a>
> ```

---

---

okay, i am sorry if my question is very much and much..
thank you :)

**update:**

okey, i've doing that, but nothing result, my page error again..

and, i want to ask again, any mistake in model_tampil->getPenyewa() ??

this is the script :

```
 function getPenyewa(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('penyewa');
    $this->db->join('jaminan','jaminan.id_penyewa = penyewa.id_penyewa');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $rows = $q->num_rows(); 
    $q_result = $q->result();

    if($rows>0){
        foreach($q_result as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

i want to input data to 2 table in my localhost, from 1 page, inputpenyewa.php..

Comment: please post only relative code not the whole thing

Comment: where is your `$records` set.... i bet the problem here is caused by the `$records` ...

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any data to the view.

```
$this->load->view('tampilpenyewa');
```

change this line to this.

```
$this->load->view('tampilpenyewa',$data);
```

You have to get the values from db. So before this line ,get value from db as

```
$data['records'] = $this->model_tampil->getPenyewa();
```

and then load the view as above, like

```
$this->load->view('tampilpenyewa',$data);
```

Hope this helps

Regards

iijb

Comment: I think there are mistakes in getPenyewa function (), because at the moment I do not give JOIN script, all the input successfully enter data into one table. and, after I give JOIN (because I want to insert data into 2 tables), suddenly error.

Answer (score 0):

In the tambah function of your controller,you are directly calling the view file without giving any data to it..

Do it like this..

```
function tambah()
{
    $ck=$this->input->post('id_penyewa');
        if($ck!='')
        {
            $this->model_tampil->insertPenyewa();
        }
    $records = $this->model_tampil->getPenyewa(); // The array returned from your whatever model function
    $this->load->view('tampilpenyewa',array('records' => $records));
}
```